# Web source parse with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-parsing

I would like to automatic download from a web site.

To make automatically, should input `dcm_no` from web site source.

I use `htmlTreeParse` and `getNodeSet`, as follow

```
doc2 <- htmlTreeParse("http://dart.fss.or.kr/dsaf001/main.do?rcpNo=20171114001007#download", useInternalNodes=TRUE, trim=TRUE)
dcmno <- getNodeSet(doc2,"//a",)
dcmno2 <- dcmno[[2]]
print(dcmno2)
dcm_no <- substr(dcmno2,10,12)
print(dcm_no)
```

But it can't print `dcm_no` only.

I search many things, but I didn't find.

How can I take `dcm_no` only from web site source?

Comment: Please, add the output for `dcmno2` and what part of it you want to extract. It's not very clear on the result.

Comment: The site's [`robots.txt`](http://dart.fss.or.kr/robots.txt) prohibits scraping of all `/dsaf001/main.do`, `/report/viewer.do`, ` /report/download.do`, `/pdf/download/` prefixed resources. Anyone who assists may be subject to civil or criminal penalties depending on the regional jurisdiction and global law enforcement agreements.

Comment: Having said that (most OPs ignore legal and ethical considerations and the following is to further encourage you to cease vs persist), the site uses frames (ugh) and also uses javascript to build the HTML tree and load up the tree-linked resources dynamically via an on-click event. HTML page surgical extraction. You'll need other, complex approaches to achieve your goal. Time wld be better spent engaging with the site proprietors to see if you can get permission and/or a data dump vs continuing down a path fraught with potential peril.